# CXF+Spring for webservice with maven

Tags: spring, maven, cxf

I'm writing a webservice project,using cxf3,spring4 and maven. When I add cxf dependencies to the pom.xml, then run the project on tomcat8.0 server, tomcat cannot be running. It shows error as below:

[tomcat failed to start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyWlW.png)

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUi1D.png)

when i change cxf3.x version to 2.2.3, the project can run normally. How to fix this problem? thank you

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@307f6b8c]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:959)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@307f6b8c]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4849)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4981)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
... 21 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
... 33 more

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
... 34 more
```

Comment: please share the stack trace here it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean and update maven project. In server of eclipse. Right click on it and do following step

1) remove the war file
2)  clean the server and restart it.

After this clean the project and build it. 
Hope! It can solve your problem.

If the issue persist, try to  do this 
Delete the target folder and do the above steps. 
 Do let me know if you stuck with issue even after following steps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Because of maven local repository address. The default local repository is "${user.home}/.m2/repository", I changed it to another disk(not C disk). When I changed to the default one, the project could be running. But I do not know why the repository path affected the project yet.